# Localization in Angular in dev environment (if there is no angular.json)

Tags: angular, localization, angular-cli, development-environment

I've just checkout a new project and I hadn't KT from previous developers and I'm trying to serve the app with localization unsuccessfully.

Within my package.json I can see the app is build for production env with this script (I've already deployed and works fine):

```
"build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --locale en --i18n-format xlf --i18n-file src/messages.en.xlf  --base-href /nameApp/"
```

On the other hand, there is no `angular.json` file in the root path (or anywhere), just an `.angular-cli.json` file.

I don't know how could be the previous developers serve this app with localization using parameters when they ran `ng serve` command. I tried to run `ng serve` with the same parameters than previous build command, find some information about how you can use angular-cli.json for internalization (I... but unsuccessfully.

The only option I can guess is they were using an `angular.json` configuration and they didn't commit that file to the repository (but I've already checked the gitignore file and I couldn't find any row for that file).

Since I'm a new angular developer, I can only assume that there is another way I don't know yet... Any suggestion or tip will we very welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `.angular-cli.json` -> `angular.json` transition happened with Angular/CLI 6: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases/tag/v6.0.0. Presumably the project you're looking at is using an older version.

Comment: That's correct, it seems that is using the 1.4.9 version. I guess that means the project cannot have an angular.json file.... so how can I serve the app in local env with localization?